# Variadic Template Parameter Expansion Inside Class member of Type std::function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I have a class called "Menu" that is used for displaying options the user can choose from. The user then selects an option and that value is processed. However, I have a child class that does not display anything, but instead just takes in an std::function with a variable number of arguments.

The signature looks like

```cpp
template<class FuncRetTy, class... FuncArgs>
class FunctionMenu : public Menu;
```

Ideally, I'd like to save a class member that has the form:

```cpp
std::function<FuncRetTy(FuncArgs...)> m_function;
```

I'd also like to automatically deduce all types from the constructor and save the values of `FuncArgs...` so these values can be run back through this function every time the overridden "`run()`" method is called. Inside `run()`, `m_function(/* FuncArgs values */)` will be called.

Any ideas are welcome. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with C++17.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. You will have to make `m_function` itself a template.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is there a way to have the function write itself with macros? Then I'd be able to just pass the function pointer to that function around.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by that. In any case, very little in modern C++ can be done with macros. The powerful templating and metaprogramming features in modern C++ make most macro-based tricks used in older C++ and C code unnecessary, and outright dangerous, since it's often used to defeat C++'s strong type-checking, and result in hard to diagnose bugs and other problems. Although it's unclear what you are attempting to accomplish here, I'm pretty confident that macros isn't the anwer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Just though of this: what about saving the `m_function`'s arguments in a tuple?

Comment: Sure. A tuple is versatile enough for this.

Comment: `std::function<FuncRetTy()> m_function;` seems enough if you bind arguments...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class Ret, class... Args>
class FunctionMenu {
    std::function<Ret(Args...)> m_function;

  public:
    FunctionMenu(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f) : m_function(f) {}

    Ret run(Args... args) {
        return f(args...);
    }
};

template<class Ret, class... Args>
FunctionMenu(std::function<Ret(Args...)>)->FunctionMenu<Ret, Args...>;

int test(int i, double d) {
    std::cout << i << ' ' << d << '\n';
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::function m = test;

    FunctionMenu fm{m};
}
```

(I did not add the Menu base class since it did not seem relevant)